# How to override shared resources including in dependency JAR

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I've got a few web projects that rely, all of them, in a common library. This library includes a few JSP files that are used to display errors (using the web.xml  error-page feature). These JSP files are included in the library shared-resources, so they are merged with the files from the application.

What I'd like would be for a way to override thoses files with ones specific to the application if I want. If I include files with the same name in the same location in the application, they are overwritten by those in the library. Is there a way, maybe using maven plugins, so I can copy files from the application AFTER the ones from the library have been copied to the target directory? This way, if the application includes its own files, they are used. If it doesn't, then those in the library are used instead.

I've tried adding a new execution of the maven-resources-plugin, using the goal  copy-resources, but they still get overwritten by the ones in the library.

Thanks for the help in advance.